# Sql Server 2005 Indexed View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have created a unique, clustered index on a view. The clustered index contains 5 columns (out of the 30 on this view), but a typical select using this view will want all 30 columns.

Doing some testing shows that the time it takes to query for the 5 columns is way faster than all 30 columns. Is this because that is just natural overhead regarding selecting on 6x as many columns, or because the indexed view is not storing the non-indexed columns in a temp table, and therefore needs to perform some extra steps to gather the missing columns (joins on base tables I guess?)

If the latter, what are some steps to prevent this? Well, even if the former... what are some ways around this!

Edit: for comparison purposes, a select on the indexed view with just the 5 columns is about 10x faster than the same query on the base tables. But a select on all columns is basically equivalent in speed to the query on the base tables.

Answer (score 0):

A clustered index, by definition, contains every field in every row in the table.  It basically is a recreation of the table, but with the physical data pages in order by the clustered index, with b-tree sorting to allow quick access to specified values of your clustered key(s).

Are you just pulling values or are you getting aggregate functions like `MIN(), MAX(), AVG(), SUM()` for the other 25 fields?

Comment: @Joda - whats in your where clause?  Adding a clustered index to a view actually executes the view query and stores the results in the index, so it's not your second concern.

Comment: where clause contains values for 3 of the 5 cols of the index

Answer (score 0):

An indexed view is a copy of the data, stored (clustered) potentially (and normally) in a different way to the base table. For all purposes

- you now have two copies of the data
- SQL Server is smart enough to see that the view and table are aliases of each other

  - for queries that involve only the columns in the indexed view
  - if the indexed view contains all columns, it is considered a full alias and can be used (substituted) by the optimizer wherever the table is queried
- the indexed view can be used as just another index for the base table

When you select only the 5 columns from `tbl` (which has an indexed view `ivw`)

- SQL Server completely ignores your table, and just gives you data from `ivw`
- because the data pages are shorter (5 columns only), more records can be grabbed into memory in each page retrieval, so you get a 5x increase in speed

When you select all 30 columns - there is no way for the indexed view to be helpful.  The query completely ignores the view, and just selects data from the base table.

**IF** you select data from all 30 columns,

- but the query filters on the first 4 columns of the indexed view,*
- and the filter is very selective (will result in a very small subset of records)

SQL Server can use the indexed view (scanning/seeking) to quickly generate a small result set, which it can then use to JOIN back to the base table to get the rest of the data.

- However, similarly to regular indexes, an index on (a,b,c,d,e) or in this case clustered indexed view on (a,b,c,d,e) does **NOT** help a query that searches on (b,d,e) because they are not the first columns in the index.